# On ng serve command ,compilation goes into infinite loop in angular 14

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, infinite, angular14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahQlW.png)

Also on single time save file it generate 5 to 6 time compile project in node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU9mv.png)

Version information.

Comment: Got any fix for this?